# Issue with VueJS event $on - running more than once

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have a structure like this

> Parent.vue -> Child.vue

Where parent is a component being called on a route or for short, the parent is the page itself with the child being a component of that parent. I also have an event bus called EventBus.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

On my child I have the following code:

```
<input type="text @change="valueChange" name="Test" />
```

Which will be handled on the VueJS methods hook:

```
methods: {
    valueChange() {
        EventBus.$emit('testEvent');
    }
},
```

Now I'm on the parent here is my code:

```
methods: {
    invokeValidationEvent() {
        console.log('test');
    },
}

created() {
    EventBus.$on('testEvent', this.invokeValidationEvent);
}
```

So here's the use case. For example I type something to the textbox, it runs the `console.log('test')` once which is the **ideal behavior**, right? Okay, lets try to say move to another 'page' then go back to the page where the parent is invoked again and type again to the textbox, `console.log('test')` is called more than once and increases the number of calls if the same process is done over and over. Is there a way to avoid this issue without using `$once` because there is a possibility that on my parent.vue, it will have say a group of same components that does the same thing so `$once` will stop calling the 2nd time after calling it the first time around.

Note: This code is just shortened. But you get the idea. My plan why I want this structure is that, I have a parent that is the 'main form', the components act as fields that I need to fill up that is why there is a need for the each components calling the same event (in this case '**testEvent**') to call more than once but avoid having to break down once I leave the parent page and go back to it and do the process again.

I also tried this on the parent component.

```
watch: {
    $route(to) {
        if (to.name !== this.$route.name) {
            EventBus.off('testEvent', this.invokeValidationEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What is the workaround of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, on my parent component I placed a guard called beforeRouteLeave

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    EventBus.$off('assignStudentStepValidation', this.invokeValidationEvent);
    next();
}
```

Presto problem solved!